# Trouble with C++ file I/O

Tags: c++, file-io

Noobie Alert. 
Ugh. I'm having some real trouble getting some basic file I/O stuff done using `<stdio.h>` or `<fstream>`. They both seem so clunky and non-intuitive to use. I mean, why couldn't C++ just provide a way to get a `char*` pointer to the first char in the file? That's all I'd ever want.

I'm doing [Project Euler Question 13](http://projecteuler.net/problem=13) and need to play with 50-digit numbers. I have the 150 numbers stored in the file `13.txt` and I'm trying to create a 150x50 array so I can play with the digits of each number directly. But I'm having tons of trouble. I've tried using the C++ `<fstream>` library and recently straight `<stdio.h>` to get it done, but something must not be clicking for me. Here's what I have;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

const unsigned N = 100;
const unsigned D = 50; 

unsigned short nums[N][D];

FILE* f = fopen("13.txt", "r");
//error-checking for NULL return

unsigned short *d_ptr = &nums[0][0];
int c = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
        continue;
    }   
    *d_ptr = (short)(c-0x30);
    ++d_ptr;
}   
fclose(f);
//do stuff
return 0;
}
```

Can someone offer some advice? Perhaps a C++ guy on which I/O library they prefer?

Comment: `while ((c = fgetc(f) != EOF))`  Is wrong.  You need to use `while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF )`

Comment: oops that was a typo. corrected! thanks

Comment: **Hint:** you don't need to use all 50 digits of each number. 99% of the problems posted on Project Euler that seem to require very large numbers or "BigNumber" libraries usually have a smart and efficient workaround that can use built-in data types.

Comment: what is c/c?  1? assuming c!=0.  otherwise, undefined?

Comment: @Inisheer says first 10 digits. nevertheless, I still would like to know why my code won't read them in

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe I completely agree. Just thought I'd throw that in there in the event you continued to have trouble with the problem.

Comment: @William: Nope, that's not correct either.  You need to change `c` to type `int` for the comparison to EOF to be unambiguous.

Comment: Getting a `char*` to the first character in a file requires reading the whole file into memory. What if the file is 1TB?

Comment: @Code-Guru: Complexity constraints dictate that some algorithms (nearly anything super-linear) will **never** be used on a dataset that can't fit in memory.  Sometimes slurping the whole thing is quite appropriate.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks fixed. but let me get this straight... fget**c**() returns an `int` ?

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe: Yes, because it can return all 256 possible values of `char`, as well as `EOF` in addition.  That's 257 values.  [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) applies at this point.  (Ok, 2**`CHAR_BIT` may not be exactly 256.  But the same argument holds)

Comment: @BenVoigt oh ok thanks. I had no idea `EOF` wasn't some particular `char` encoding. merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice efficient solution (but doesn't work with pipes):

```
std::vector<char> content;
FILE* f = fopen("13.txt", "r");
// error-checking goes here
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
content.resize(ftell(f));
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_BEGIN);
fread(&content[0], 1, content.size(), f);
fclose(f);
```

Here's another:

```
std::vector<char> content;
struct stat fileinfo;
stat("13.txt", &fileinfo);
// error-checking goes here
content.resize(fileinfo.st_size);
FILE* f = fopen("13.txt", "r");
// error-checking goes here
fread(&content[0], 1, content.size(), f);
// error-checking goes here
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Been very helpful. You prefer using stdio? Additionally, can you see why my code may be wrong? I really just need to be able to access individual digits.

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe: What's wrong with your code?  Doesn't compile?  Crashes?  Bad values in memory?  Since you opened the file in binary mode, you may also want to skip over `'\r'` characters.

Comment: Lol I found the bug. One of those bugs where you just want to slam your head against a wall. In any case, since you've been the most helpful I'll accept your answer :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an fstream. The one problem you have is that you obviously can't fit the numbers in the file into any of C++'s native numeric types (double, long long, etc.)

Reading them into strings is pretty easy though:

```
std::fstream in("13.txt");

std::vector<std::string> numbers((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in)),
                                  std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

That will read in each number into a string, so the number that was on the first line will be in `numbers[0]`, the second line in `numbers[1]`, and so on.

If you really want to do the job in C, it can still be quite a lot easier than what you have above:

```
char *dupe(char const *in) {
    char *ret;
    if (NULL != (ret=malloc(strlen(in)+1))
        strcpy(ret, in);
    return ret;
}

// read the data:
char buffer[256];
char *strings[256];
size_t pos = 0;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)
    strings[pos++] = dupe(buffer);
```

Comment: Why write your own `strdup`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Because `strdup` isn't standard, and trying to write your own by that name (or any other starting with `str`) gives undefined behavior.

Comment: I guess if you're not counting the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the one hundred 50 digit numbers from a file, why not read them directly in from a character constant?

You could start your code out with:

```
static const char numbers[] = 
 "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"
 "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538"...
```

With a semicolon at the last line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done that in previous questions. But doing it this way would mean I'd need to manually insert 300 double-quoation marks in. Also I really need to learn to do file I/O lol

Comment: When I've had to insert the quotation marks for Euler problems I've always done a search and replace on newlines to get the quotation marks.

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe I don't know about you, but my text editor (vim) lets me do that by placing the cursor on the first column, pressing Ctrl+V for column selection mode, then `300j` to go 300 lines down, then `I` to insert, typing `"` and pressing Esc to stop inserting text.

Comment: As razeh and R. Martinho allude to, that's quite easy if you know your editor.  Still, learning to do file I/O is a worthy project; you'll need that skill in the future.

Comment: ya I'm using vim. But if I havn't gotten ahold of file I/O I definitely  havn't learned all the vim tricks yet ;) Thanks for the tip though!